# WPF MVVM - Get access to DependencyProperty of DataGrid in View from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, dependency-properties

In my View I have a `DataGrid` which stores objects of 2 descending types. Every row has a Button with a Command connected to the ViewModel. In the ViewModel I need to find out which type of object has been chosen.

The question is what is the best and simple way of accessing `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid` from the `Execute` command method in a ViewModel?

So far I did it like this:

```
var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>()
    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);

var dataGrid = (DataGrid) window.FindName("MyGridName");
...
```

**UPDATE - Xaml:**

```
<DataGrid Name="MyGridName" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button Name="OptionsBtn" Margin="5" Width="auto"
                  Height="30" Content="Options"
                  Command="{Binding ElementName=ElementsViewWindow,
                      Path=DataContext.ShowOptionsMenuCommand}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Bind the `SelectedItem` of your Grid to some VM property or use `CommandParameters` and stop whatever you are trying to do...

Comment: show the command as in your Xaml and how you bind it. I'd be pleased to then show you how to take that Command Parameter approach!

Comment: `<Button Name="OptionsBtn" Margin="5" Width="auto" Height="30" Content="Options" Command="{Binding ElementName=ElementsViewWindow, Path=DataContext.ShowOptionsMenuCommand}" CommandParameter="{Bidning .}"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take the right MVVM approach this is very easy to do. All you need is to define the item collection of you entities which will be bound to `ItemsSource` of your `DataGrid` and a property which will be bound to `SelectedItem` of your `DataGrid`. Then in your command you simply reference your selected item property of your model to access the selected item in your `DataGrid`.

Here is an example implementation with MVVM Light. First you define an observable collection of your entities:

```
public const string ItemsCollectionPropertyName = "ItemsCollection";
private ObservableCollection<DataItem> _itemsCollection = null;
public ObservableCollection<DataItem> ItemsCollection
{
    get
    {
        return _itemsCollection;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_itemsCollection == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _itemsCollection = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(ItemsCollectionPropertyName);
    }
}
```

Then you define a property to hold the selected item:

```
public const string SelectedItemPropertyName = "SelectedItem";
private DataItem _selectedItem = null;
public DataItem SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedItem == value)
        {
            return;
        }

        _selectedItem = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedItemPropertyName);
    }
}
```

After that you define a command to handle business logic:

```
private ICommand _doWhateverCommand;
public ICommand DoWhateverCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_doWhateverCommand == null)
        {
            _doWhateverCommand = new RelayCommand(
                () => { /* do your stuff with SelectedItem here */  },
                () => { return SelectedItem != null; }
            );
        }
        return _doWhateverCommand;
    }
}
```

Finally you create view elements and bind them to the `ViewModel`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
<Button Content="Do stuff" Command="{Binding DoWhateverCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> The question is what is the best and simple way of accessing SelectedItem property of DataGrid from Execute command function in a ViewModel?

Just add a property to the view model class where the `ShowOptionsMenuCommand` property is defined and bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid` to this one:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyGridName" ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}" ... >
```

Then you can access the source property (`SelectedElement` or whatever you choose to call it) directly from the `Execute` method.

The other option would be to pass the item as a `CommandParameter` to the command:

```
<Button Name="OptionsBtn" ... Content="Options" 
        Command="{Binding ElementName=ElementsViewWindow, Path=DataContext.ShowOptionsMenuCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```